# MongoDB Document size limit 16mb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Does Document refer to the actual document, eg. the whole collection, or does it refer to the documents inside the collection?

Similar question was asked here: [Mongodb collection maximum size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735071/mongodb-collection-maximum-size-limit)

But I dont really understand the answer.

**Does Document size Limit 16 mb refer to a single Document inside a collection or to the whole collection?**

My case: I am building a dictionary. I have about 20 thousand words, for every word I want to save 6 translations (German, French, Spanish, ect), I also want to save frequency, synonyms, example sentences, definitions and so on. Also I would like to scan a text corpus for a word and save the 15 most frequent words before and after the word.

I did this with 2000 Words and the whole collection size is already at 13MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Document refers to the document in the collection. In other words, each individual BSON in your MongoDB deployment cannot pass 16MB limit (you can read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)). With 2000 documents hitting 13MB, you shouldn't have any problem doing what you are doing.